# How to store results in a recursive function and will my method even work?

Tags: python, function, recursion

My first attempt at writing a recursive function that lists all permutations of strings characters.

If I set a list to be empty, then add the results to this list, I find that the list gets reset to empty with each call of the function.

I know what I have at the moment is also wrong as the for loop will be broken by the return statement. But this is where I am stuck, how to save the results i.e. each separate permutation, without having the list reset to empty with each call? I am not allowed use global variables, this is an exercise from an MIT open Courseware class.

Also would like to know if my method will even work? not sure if how I have sliced the string up will work.

Can anyone shed light on how I can make a list of all the permutations within the function? and if my method even has any chance of working?

```
def get_permutations(sequence):

if len(sequence) == 1:
    return sequence


else:
    return (sequence[i] + get_permutations(sequence[0:i-1] + sequence[i +
1 : len(sequence)]) for i in range(len(sequence)))
```

Now the output is

```
<generator object get_permutations.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x102b3b9d0>
```

Comment: There are many SO questions -- and other places -- that detail how to accumulate results as you traverse a recursion tree.  In general, you have to build the partial result list and return that as your function value.  As for "will it work?", Stack Overflow is not a testing service -- what happens when you run it?  That's *your* job.

Comment: As I said, I mean the method, not the exact code. Wondering if the method has actual merit.

Comment: That is a design / code review issue -- not for Stack Overflow.

Comment: where would I ask?

Comment: I don't know.  First of all, it depends on exactly where you're uncertain.  Your approach is certainly valid, as you took it from a proven algorithm.  I would think that your implementation is what you're really questioning, and that requires testing.  For "where to post", you should go to the Stack Exchange main pages and review the existing groups.  Code Review only covers improvement of working code.

Comment: I didnt take it from anywhere. I just got this as problem set and seemed like a way to do it using recursion. Is there another site where people can help beginners? I thought that's what this site was for

Comment: Ah, ha!  Okay ... you've reinvented a useful approach.

Comment: I see your confusion, then.  Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

You can't `return` more than once!  Instead of returning each value from inside of a loop, you want to build a list and return that.  That would look something like this:

```
def get_permutations(sequence):
    if len(sequence) == 1:
        # base case
        return sequence
    
    # Each recursive call needs to be on a subset of sequence so it gets
    # smaller each time and eventually reaches the base case...
    return [
        sequence[i] + get_permutations(sequence[0:i-1] + sequence[i+1:len(sequence)]) 
        for i in range(len(sequence))
    ]
```

There are still some errors here in how you're reducing to your base case and how you're building the list, but hopefully this gets you pointed in the right direction!

Comment: Yea I originally tried with a list but I'm not allowed use global variables so I had to initialize it to be empty but with each call of the function( recursively(?)) this list was emptied .   Can you expand on how I can use a list without it being global? also for the base case if it is length 1 then there is only the identity permutation? so what else but to return itself. . .

Comment: I don't understand the followup question -- the above code doesn't use any `global`, nor is there any reason for it to do so.  Nothing in the above code "empties" the list.  There is indeed a problem with the base case -- rather than returning the list itself, it should be returning a list containing the list (i.e. `[sequence]` rather than `sequence`) since the return value is supposed to be a list of lists!

Comment: Yes it doesnt use the list as I originally tried using a list but everytime I ran the code I got just an empty list as it was set to empty with every call of function, only way I could see around that was to use a global list but it's prohibited in this exercise. I have edited the code as you suggested so there is only one return statement, I'm getting an output I have never encountered "<generator object get_permutations.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x102b3b9d0>"  I do see what you mean about it returning a string instead of a list of strings

Comment: If you're getting a generator object it means you used `()` instead of `[]` in that final return statement.

Answer (score 0):

Since the function is supposed to return a list of permutations, you should use a nested `for` clause in the list comprehension to iterate through the returning list from the recursive call to append to the current value at index `i`. Also, in the base case the function should also return a list of string characters, even it's a list of just one character:

```
def get_permutations(sequence):
    if len(sequence) == 1:
        return [sequence]
    return [
        sequence[i] + s
        for i in range(len(sequence))
        for s in get_permutations(sequence[:i] + sequence[i + 1:])
    ]
```

so that:

```
get_permutations('abc')
```

returns:

```
['abc', 'acb', 'bac', 'bca', 'cab', 'cba']
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm not familiar with the enumerate method or using two variable as you have, can I ask, are i and v letters or numbers? do you think my code can be modified using basic commands or would I need a whole rewrite. I couldn't claim to know or properly understand your solution as it uses methods I haven't covered yet . .

Comment: I see. I've updated my answer to iterate over `range(len(sequence))` like you do then.